# How to sort multi dimensional array in php?

Tags: php

Id like to sort the following array by element `[0][0],[1][0],[2][0],[3][0],[4][0]`

```
$cars = array
  (
  array($_COOKIE[pr1],$_COOKIE['1']),
  array($_COOKIE[pr2],$_COOKIE['2']),
  array($_COOKIE[pr3],$_COOKIE['3']),
  array($_COOKIE[pr4],$_COOKIE['4']),
  array($_COOKIE[pr5],$_COOKIE['5'])
  );
```

Comment: by what sequence?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
array_multisort($cars[0],
            $cars[1],
            $cars[2],
            $cars[3],
            $cars[4]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below for sorting as per your order.

```
function multiarray_sort ($cars, $key) {
    $sorter=array();
    $ret=array();
    reset($cars);
    foreach ($cars as $ii => $va) {
        $sorter[$ii]=$va[$key];
    }
    asort($sorter);
    foreach ($sorter as $ii => $va) {
        $ret[$ii]=$cars[$ii];
    }
    $cars=$ret;
}

multiarray_sort($cars,"order");
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorting multi dimensional arrays can be done using this :

```
bool array_multisort ( array &$array1 [, mixed $array1_sort_order = SORT_ASC [, mixed $array1_sort_flags = SORT_REGULAR [, mixed $... ]]] )
```

Please [click here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) for detailed information.

Comment: why did people downvote this answer? I provided a link to the author so that he can learn and next time before posting a question search properly. Strange people behavior.

Comment: This information would be better placed (if at all) as a comment on the question.  This is a generic answer that ignores the OP's sample input and was mindlessly copy-pasted from the manual.  (not my downvote -- I am seeing this as I review low-quality posts in the moderation queue)